# Pushing a directory of code to GitHub from Android

Tags: applications, shell, file-management, 8.1-oreo, backup-manager

I have a directory structure containing code on my Android phone. I would like to push the code to GitHub. I have downloaded the FastHub app and tried the mobile and desktop versions of my GitHub account but am still unable to do it because I want to upload everything in one go.

Perhaps I need a shell client with git installed or added on on Android.

Can someone please tell me how I can accomplish my task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FastHub is just a GitHub client, so it's of no use where Git is needed. As you suspected this requires a Git client, though it doesn't need to be run in a shell.

Up to at least Android 10 [MGit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manichord.mgit) is one useable option.

1. GitHub: When starting a new repo, create a repo with a readme so it can be cloned immediately. Copy the URL to the repo, e.g. `https://github.com/username/reponame`.
2. MGit: Go to Settings and set the storage location for repos if the root of emulated external storage isn't a good spot.
3. MGit: Press `+`, paste the repo URL into the "Remote URL" field, check "Clone recursively" if necessary (no idea if that works), and press "Clone". It should quickly start the process, but it can be slow if it's a huge repo.
4. Copy and paste the files with your code into the repo directory using a file manager. Recommend copying so there's a backup in case something goes wrong while still learning this process, but users choice.
5. MGit: Go into the repo and move over to the Status area to confirm your files are being detected.
6. MGit: Open the menu by pressing the hamburger or swiping from the right, press "Add all to stage", and then "Commit", and enter your commit info. Recommend filling the optional Author field so it doesn't use a default, which looks odd on GitHub. Press "Commit" to finalize it.
7. MGit: Open the menu and press "Push" and then "origin". Now the login..
8. GitHub: Go to Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access tokens ([easy link](https://github.com/settings/tokens)). Press "Generate new token" and confirm password if necessary.
9. GitHub, PAT: It's good to add a note specific to the app + repo as it's easy to forget what each is for, and the note apparently can't be changed after. For the scope select "repo", then scroll down and press "Generate token". Make sure the token is copied before leaving the page.
10. MGit: Enter the PAT you just created as the password on the login. Now it should successfully push.

If a shell client is preferred Termux may work. If a real shell client is preferred a Linux chroot environment like [UserLAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tech.ula) is the way to go, as it's almost a real Linux install. Beyond Android 10 this will all probably fail because of storage permission changes.